# React Native: Passing data fetched from firebase to Flatlist

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I am fetching a list of items from firebase to be passed to a Flatlist component.

Right now I do:

```
fetch('https://demo.firebaseio.com/posts.json', {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(items => {

            items = Object.entries(items).map(item => ({
                 ...item[1], 
                 key: item[0]
            }));

            this.setState({
                posts: items,
                isLoading: false
            })

        }).catch(err => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(err));
        });
```

And then:

```
<FlatList data={this.state.posts} renderItem={({item}) => {
                return <Text>{item.title}}</Text>
            }} keyExtractor={(item) => { return item.key; }} />
```

This works, but it is not efficient, I need to loop through the items twice, once to convert it to an array and another to render each item on flatlist, this will be a nightmare with large datasets.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what is the structure of your data?

Comment: @JuniusL. Firebase returns an object with a key and and a object as value: LhfJHe7IgF5SzyKYfDr: {city: "City", description: "Description", title: "Title"}
-LhfUq6tiKa11mo94dxu: {city: "City", description: "Description test", title: "Title test"}

Comment: Why do you need the keyExtractor? The entire point of the `Object.entries` seems to be to get nothing more than the index. But both `renderItem` and `keyExtractor` are simple maps that already provide you with the index which you can use as a key.

Comment: I need to convert the object to array, any suggestion?

Comment: I missed the fact that you are getting objects back from fireBase. You should specify that in the question. Not in the comments. With that being said why you cannot get that data from fireBase as an array? You have no control over the service end point? If no then this is your best bet. 2 iterations are simply needed due to one is to transform the object to array and the other to render.